# Android Room database RxAndroid, Exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, rx-android

Currently, I am fetching data from Web API using RxAndroid and Retrofit, and want to store that Data in Room database but getting an exception

As I search and found that, room database operations won't work on UI thread so I added `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` in RXAndroid
still it is throwing

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access the database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

```
public void onClickLogin(View view) {

             io.reactivex.Observable
             .zip(getLogin(Constants.EMAILID, Constants.PASSWORD),
             getUserInfo(Constants.EMAILID, Constants.PASSWORD),
            getProductDetails(Constants.EMAILID, Constants.PASSWORD).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        new Function3<List<LoginModule>,
                                List<UserInfoModule>, ProductModule, AllZipData>() {
                            @Override
                            public AllZipData apply(List<LoginModule> loginModuleList, List<UserInfoModule> useerInfoModules, ProductModule productModule) throws Exception {

                                AllZipData allZipData = new AllZipData();
                                allZipData.setLoginModuleList(loginModuleList);
                                allZipData.setUserInfoModuleList(UserInfoModule);
                                allZipData.setProductModule(productModule);

                                return allZipData;
                            }
                        }).subscribe(new Observer<AllZipData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                compositeDisposable.add(d);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(AllZipData allZipData) {


                MyDatabase MyDatabase = MyDatabase.getInstance(context);

                for (int i = 0; i < allZipData.getUserInfoModuleList().size(); i++) {

                    UserInfoTable userInfoTable = new UserInfoTable();
                    userInfoTable.setValue1(allZipData.getUserInfoModuleList().get(i).getValue1());
                    userDatabase.userDao().insertUserInfo(userInfoTable);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onError: all zip data " + e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: all data zipped");
            }
        });
}
```

how to solve this exception using RxAndroid.

**How to add retryWhen();?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does this exception happen? If it is in `onNext`, that's because you specified `observeOn(mainThread())` thus the database access happens on the main thread.

Try this

```java
Observable.zip(
    getLogin(Constants.EMAILID, Constants.PASSWORD)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),  // <--------------------------------
    getUserInfo(Constants.EMAILID, Constants.PASSWORD)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),  // <--------------------------------
    getProductDetails(Constants.EMAILID, Constants.PASSWORD)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())   // <--------------------------------
)
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())             // <--------------------------------
.doOnNext(allZipData -> {
    MyDatabase MyDatabase = MyDatabase.getInstance(context);

    for (int i = 0; i < allZipData.getUserInfoModuleList().size(); i++) {

         UserInfoTable userInfoTable = new UserInfoTable();

         userInfoTable.setValue1(
             allZipData.getUserInfoModuleList().get(i).getValue1()
         );

         userDatabase.userDao().insertUserInfo(userInfoTable);
    }
})
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new Observer<AllZipData>() {
    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        compositeDisposable.add(d);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(AllZipData allZipData) {
        // notify UI here?
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onError: all zip data " + e.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: all data zipped");
    }
});
```

Comment: How to add retryWhen()?

Comment: Where, why, how, what?

Comment: whenever network call throws IO exception i have to retry 3 times

Comment: Please ask a separate question.

Comment: I already post separate question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57429527/how-to-add-retrywhen-for-limited-time-eg-3-time-retries-only-getting-ioexcep

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line still needs some `RxJava` operations :

```
userDatabase.userDao().insertUserInfo(userInfoTable);
```

I believe the `insertUserInfo` in your dao should return a `Completable`.

Comment: Here is code which i wrote in interface     @Insert
    void insertUserInfo (UserInfo userInfo);

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.

Clearly says that you're running on `MainThread` of your application, which leads to freezing of the screen. You should handle your queries or long running operations on background thread of your application.

Change this

```
observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

to

```
observeOn(Schedulers.io())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) to perform operation. Check this

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map {
        }
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnSubscribe {

        }
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<AllZipData>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                compositeDisposable.add(d);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(AllZipData allZipData) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

            }

        })
```